# Process table limit

Tags: linux, process, process-management

I was wondering if the Process Table in linux OS has a limit.
Can it get full? And if so, what would I do to make space (maybe try deleting entries for zombie processes) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run `sysctl kernel.pid_max kernel.threads-max` to see the current maximum limits for processes and threads respectively. (Each process occupies at least one thread; more if multithreaded.)

The "factory default" process limit might be 32768 on desktop-oriented distributions, or something rather higher in enterprise-oriented distributions. You can use `/etc/sysctl.conf` to increase the limits up to 4194304 (at least) in modern 64-bit systems.

(The maximum was 4194304 in kernel version 3.10.25; it may have been increased further since then.)

You cannot delete zombie processes, they are already dead. What you should do is **kill the evil zombie master,** i.e. the parent process of the zombies, because the presence of zombies indicates the parent is not doing its job properly. Once the negligent parent process has been killed, the zombies will get adopted by process #1 which will normally clean them up pretty much immediately.

The parent process should either always check the return code of its child processes when it gets notified that its child has died, or it should arrange for the child processes to get disowned at start-up, so the process #1 (usually `/sbin/init`) can adopt them. Process #1 has a special responsibility of adopting any otherwise parentless processes and taking care of their death notifications.